# Ver BD SQLite no Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou a tentar visualizar a minha BD Sqlite no Android Device Monitor, mas na pasta `data`, não me aparece nenhum ficheiro para poder exportar e assim não consigo ver a minha BD.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que posso estar a fazer mal?

Comment: Adicione o código da criação do seu banco no seu aplicativo.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe, em que medida é q pode ser o problema daí? A app funciona bem e a BD tambem...

Comment: Pra ver como você está criando o BD, se está informando algum path especifico na hora de criá-lo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só é possível aceder ao conteúdo da pasta `Data` caso o *device* seja um emulador<sup>*</sup>.

A BD fica localizada em:

> data > data > your-package-name > databases > your-database-file.

A razão por não aparecerem sub-directórios na pasta `Data` é o *adb* não ter permissões para ler o seu conteúdo.

Se estiver a usar o Android Studio 3.0 ou superior use o Device File Explorer.
Com ele é possível ver todo o conteúdo da pasta `Data`, desde de que o dispositivo seja um emulador.

Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/279944/2541) e/ou a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer.html) para mais detalhes.

<sup>*</sup><sub>Ou "rooted device"</sub>

Comment: Obrigada! E sem emulator como faço?Há alguma forma?

Comment: Então a pergunta está mal elaborada, porque no print, a pasta data não possui subdiretórios. Mas a resposta está correta mesmo.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Não tem/aparecem sub-diretórios porque o *adb* não tem permissões para ler o conteúdo da pasta

Comment: Veja [Export SQLite data from your Android device](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/export-sqlite-data-from-your-android-device/)

Comment: Estranho, aqui no eclipse quando eu estava mexendo com o desenvolvimento de um app, aparecia normalmente no AVD Monitor.

Comment: Pessoal `aceder` foi adicionado do acordo gramatical? :) Significar acessar?

Comment: @rubStackOverflow De acordo com [este dicionario](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/aceder), signfica ter acesso.