# Criação de banco SQLite no smartphone

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estou com duvidas em relação a criação do banco no SQlite no smartphone via USB. Quando eu rodo meu programa no emulador, o banco funciona perfeitamente e sem problemas. Mas percebo que quando faço o mesmo, emulando o app no meu smartphone, o programa não cria o banco de dado (o que tecnicamente deveria ocorrer).Em relação a isso, pergunto:

- Por que no smartphone não está criando o banco?
- Como faço pra criar o banco no smartphone via USB? Quais outras maneiras para criar o banco no aparelho?

Como pedido, o código de uma das tabelas:

```
public class BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MPM_BD.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;

    public static final String TABLE_USUARIO = "MPM_USUARIO";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NOME = "nome";
    public static final String COLUMN_SENHA = "senha";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERNR = "pernr";
    public static final String COLUMN_CODUSU = "codusu";
    public static final String COLUMN_LOGIN = "login";

    public BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_USUARIO + " ("
                + COLUMN_ID + " integer not null primary key autoincrement, "
                + COLUMN_NOME + " text, "
                + COLUMN_SENHA + " text, "
                + COLUMN_PERNR + " integer, "
                + COLUMN_CODUSU + " integer, "
                + COLUMN_LOGIN + " text)";
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USUARIO);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

BancoDAO:

```
public class BDUserBancoDao {
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private String[] columns = {BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID, BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_NOME,
        BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_SENHA, BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_PERNR,
        BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_CODUSU, BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_LOGIN};
private BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper sqliteOpenHelper;

public BDUserBancoDao(Context context) {
    sqliteOpenHelper = new BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = sqliteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    sqliteOpenHelper.close();
}

public boolean verificaDados(String codigoUsuario){
    long cod = Integer.parseInt(codigoUsuario);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper.TABLE_USUARIO, columns, BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + cod, null, null, null, null, null);

    if((cursor!=null&& cursor.getCount()>0)) return true;
    else return false;
}

//Le os dados do usuario e retorna seus valores (id, nome, senha,pernr,codusu,login)
public BDUserGetterSetter lerUsuario(String codigoUsuario) {
    long cod = Integer.parseInt(codigoUsuario);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper.TABLE_USUARIO, columns, BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + cod, null, null, null, null);

    BDUserGetterSetter newDadosUser = new BDUserGetterSetter();
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    newDadosUser.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
    newDadosUser.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
    newDadosUser.setSenha(cursor.getString(2));
    newDadosUser.setPernr(cursor.getString(3));
    newDadosUser.setCodusu(cursor.getInt(4));
    newDadosUser.setLogin(cursor.getString(5));
    cursor.close();

    return newDadosUser;
}

public void deletarDados (){
    database.delete(sqliteOpenHelper.TABLE_USUARIO,null,null);
}

public String inserirDados(BDUserGetterSetter dadosUser) {
    // inserindo valores
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    long resultado;

    valores.put(sqliteOpenHelper.COLUMN_CODUSU, dadosUser.getCodusu());
    valores.put(sqliteOpenHelper.COLUMN_NOME, dadosUser.getNome());
    valores.put(sqliteOpenHelper.COLUMN_LOGIN, dadosUser.getLogin());
    valores.put(sqliteOpenHelper.COLUMN_SENHA, dadosUser.getSenha());
    valores.put(sqliteOpenHelper.COLUMN_PERNR, dadosUser.getPernr());

    resultado = database.insert(BDUserCustomSQLiteOpenHelper.TABLE_USUARIO, null, valores);       

    if (resultado == -1){
        return "Erro ao baixar registro";
    }else{
        return "Registro baixado com sucesso";
    }
}
```

**OBS:** Não sei se isso ajuda em algo, mas no DMMS, na parte do smartphone, o diretório "data" está vazio.

Comment: Primeiramente, inclua o seu código de criação na pergunta, sem ver o código não tem como a gente verificar o problema.

Comment: Em principio o banco deveria ter sido criado no *smartphone* como foi no emulador mas, como disse o @DiegoFelipe, sem conhecer o código será difícil responder à pergunta.

Comment: Em relação a "o diretório "data" está vazio." isso é normal no caso do  *smartphone* veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107481/2541).