# Localizar banco SQLite no Android

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Seguinte, estou criando uma aplicação para Android, onde utilizo um banco SQLite local, nunca deu nenhum tipo de problema de cadastro ou consulta de banco, por isso nunca precisei pegar o banco direto no emulador, porém agora estou precisando, o problema é, não consigo localizar esse banco, ele está criado, possui dados, apenas não localizo. Utilizo o Android Studio, já olhei no Android Device Monitor, porém não consigo abrir a pasta "data",pois consta como vazia. O estranho é que se eu tentar criar uma pasta "data/data" ele fala que o arquivo já existe. Como posso recuperar esse banco?

Comment: Somente através do próprio aplicativo. Esse diretório é protegido e só pode ser acessado por quem o cria. Você vai precisar "copiar" esse arquivo para um diretório público antes de ser capaz de encontrá-lo

Comment: Mas o Emulador não possui permissões para isso? Se não como eu copio o banco para uma pasta pública.

Comment: Acredito que não. O SO é quem gerencia, não a plataforma (emulador). Como eu disse, para copiar você precisa codificar no proprio app. Ex.: Ao clicar em um determinado botão, copia o arquivo de banco para a pasta "Downloads".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A razão por não aparecerem sub-directórios na pasta `Data` é o **adb** não ter permissões para ler o seu conteúdo.

Use o [Device File Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer.html).

Pode abri-lo através de **View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer** ou clicando no botão existente na zona lateral inferior direita do Android Studio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível interagir com o conteúdo clicando com o botão direito para criar um novo, salvar no pc o arquivo ou pasta seleccionado, excluir ou sincronizar.

**Notas:**

- Requer Android Studio 3.0 ou superior
- O conteúdo da pasta `Data` só é visível caso o dispositivo seja um emulador.

Comment: Não existe essa opção no meu Android Studio

Comment: Qual é a versão do Android Studio que usa?

Comment: 2.3.3, vou atualizar

Comment: Valeu, deu certo!

Answer (score 4):

Caso você não encontre o arquivo através da janela "Device File Explorer", você pode utilizar o código abaixo:

```
try {

    /* Captura o arquivo original */
    File src = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), "//data//".concat(getPackageName()).concat("//databases//SEU-BANCO.db"));

    /* Captura o caminho do arquivo de destino */
    File dst = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().concat("/SEU-BANCO-BACKUP.db"));

    /* Cria o arquivo de destino */
    dst.createNewFile();

    /* Abre o arquivo original e o de destino para leitura e escrita, respectivamente */
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(src);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dst);
    int b = 0;

    /* Ler o conteúdo em byte do arquivo original e escreve no arquivo de destino */
    while ((b = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(b);
    }

    /* Fecha as conexões */
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Valeu,mais tarde vou precisar de copiar o banco para outra pasta